# Laraval 10 use Vite JS -> [plugin:inject] rollup-plugin-inject: failed to parse

Tags: javascript, css, npm, vite, laravel-10

I need a little explanation of how Vite JS works on the build.

I'll tell you what it's about.
I have a project with a CSS, images and JS folder in the resources folder. I also have a vendors folder where I have various JS and CSS libraries as well as fonts and images.
App.js

```js
import './bootstrap';

import.meta.glob([
    '../vendors/common/fonts/**',
    '../vendors/common/images/**',
    '../vendors/common/webfonts/**',
]);

// JS
import '../js/script.js';
import '../js/slider-script.js';

// JS LIB
import '../vendors/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js';
import '../vendors/wow/wow.js';
import '../vendors/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.js';

// CSS LIB
import '../vendors/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css';
import '../vendors/fontawesome/css/all.min.css';
import '..//vendors/animate/animate.min.css';
import '../vendors/youtube-popup/youtube-popup.css';
import '../vendors/icomoon/style.css';
import '../vendors/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.css';
import '../vendors/owl-carousel/owl.theme.default.min.css';
import '../css/style.css';
```

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import inject from '@rollup/plugin-inject';
import path from "path";

export default defineConfig({
    build: {
        assetsInlineLimit: 0,
    },
    plugins: [
        inject({
            jQuery: "jquery",
            "window.jQuery": "jquery",
            $: "jquery"
        }),
        laravel({
            input: ['resources/js/app.js'],
            refresh: true,
        })
    ]
});
```

I can't understand why when I run npm run build I get problems in the console:

The folder of build :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0n6Fr.png)

And here are the errors when I launch the build. I'd like the fonts and images in the vendors folder to be added to the assets during the build, but it doesn't work.

> [plugin:inject] rollup-plugin-inject: failed to parse /home/www/laralve10/resources/vendors/youtube-popup/you
> tube-popup.css. Consider restricting the plugin to particular files via options.include

> [plugin:inject] rollup-plugin-inject: failed to parse /home/www/laralve10/resources/vendors/icomoon/style.css
> . Consider restricting the plugin to particular files via options.include

> [plugin:inject] rollup-plugin-inject: failed to parse /home/www/laralve10resources/css/style.css. Consider r
> estricting the plugin to particular files via options.include

> [plugin:inject] rollup-plugin-inject: failed to parse /home/www/laralve10/resources/vendors/fontawesome/css/a
> ll.min.css. Consider restricting the plugin to particular files via options.include

for the rest everything is ok, images are built in the asset folder with css and js

✓ 85 modules transformed.
public/build/assets/banner-one-shape-1-D9OP_mXl.png

I haven't created an images folder in public. Is this compulsory? Is it also possible to create an images sub-folder in assets so that the images can be inserted on their own?